# td width is bigger than it should be

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/kpz8hxuy/

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 50%;">
<h2>Loremipsum</h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="#">Loremipsum</a></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 1px; background: #ddd;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<h3>Loremipsum</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="#">Loremipsum</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I set the td width to 1px but its not 1px, its 6px.

Cant really figure out why it behaves like this.

best regards

Comment: Just an advise, avoid using tables for layout purposes. There are couple of ways out there to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the table-layout is auto. Even when you've defined the width of the table td it will expand depending on its contents. So, using fixed layout for the table wouldn't automatically expand the contents rather it would be set within the defined width.

```
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

---

And when you are trying to use td width in just 1px, I suppose you're trying to use a border, so, use border instead of defining the td width.

```
table td{
   border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `border-left: 1px solid #ddd` on your `td` instead of this 1px column. 
You shouldn't use a column of your table for layout purpose.

Comment: Yep did it with border now. I use tables because its easier for the client to change the content.